# Office Scripts: needed parameter not visible in PowerAutomate

Tags: excel, typescript, power-automate, office-scripts

I have written a quite complicated Office Scripts with passing parameters from previous steps in PowerAutomate. It worked, but now it doesn't work. I think since last Monday. The problem is I don't know if the script gets too complicated or there is a change in the PA environment.
The script uses interface options, nested functions. There is no syntax errors (at least I don't see it). And finally, when I keep the script super easy, there is a box to pass the parameter (called draftTab here), but when I add some lines of code, the box disappears in PA. I wasn't able to figure out which lines make the script invalid.
Do you have any ideas on that?

Script here:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, draftTab: string) {

  let wsArr: ExcelScript.Worksheet[] = workbook.getWorksheets();
  let libContent: clsLibraryContent = {
    Filename: workbook.getName(),
    Modules: [],
  };

  wsArr.forEach(ws => {
    
    let wsName: string = ws.getName();
    console.log("loop: " + wsName);
    let shtRawDraftName: string = draftTab.slice(0, draftTab.indexOf("_DRAFT"));
    console.log("look for: " + shtRawDraftName);

    if (wsName != 'Index' && wsName != 'Changes' && wsName != 'Changes_VL' && wsName != 'Header' && wsName != 'Other_Identifiers' && wsName == shtRawDraftName) {
      console.log("ifs passed " + shtRawDraftName);
      
      let usedRange: ExcelScript.Range = ws.getUsedRange();
      let headersRow: number = usedRange.find('Variable Name', { completeMatch: true }).getRowIndex();
      let lastRow: number = usedRange.getRowCount();

      let RDS: clsModule = {
        TabName: ws.getName(),
        Header: ws.getCell(0, 0).getValue().toString(),
        Description: ws.getCell(1, 0).getValue().toString(),
        Label: ws.getCell(2, 0).getValue().toString(),
        Name: ws.getCell(3, 0).getValue().toString(),
        KeyStructure: ws.getCell(4, 0).getValue().toString(),
        CurrentVersion: ws.getCell(5, 0).getValue().toString(),
        PreviousVersion: ws.getCell(6, 0).getValue().toString(),
        Comments: ws.getCell(7, 0).getValue().toString(),
        Variables: [],
      };

      for (let i = headersRow + 1; i < lastRow; i++) {

        let newVariable: string = ws.getCell(i, 0).getValue().toString().trim();
        console.log("Cell A content: " + newVariable + ";");

        if (newVariable != "") {
          let variable: clsVariable = {
            Name: ws.getCell(i, 0).getValue().toString().trim(),
            Label: ws.getCell(i, 1).getValue().toString().trim(),
            Type: ws.getCell(i, 2).getValue().toString().trim(),
            CollectionLength: ws.getCell(i, 3).getValue().toString().trim(),
            Format: ws.getCell(i, 4).getValue().toString().trim(),
            Class: ws.getCell(i, 6).getValue().toString().trim(),
            Required: ws.getCell(i, 7).getValue().toString().trim(),
            ValidValues: [],
          };

          for (let j: number = 8; j < 30; j++) {

            let configContent: string = ws.getCell(i, j).getValue().toString().trim();

            if (configContent != "") {

              let config: string = ws.getCell(headersRow, j).getValue().toString().trim();
              variable[config] = configContent;
              console.log(config + ": " + variable[config]);

            }
          };

          let validValContent: string = ws.getCell(i, 5).getValue().toString().trim();

          if (validValContent != "") {

            do {

              let equalSignIndex: number = validValContent.indexOf("=");

              let validValue: clsValidValue = {
                CodedValue: validValContent.slice(0, equalSignIndex),
                UserString: validValContent.slice(equalSignIndex + 1),
              };

              variable.ValidValues.push(validValue);
              ++i;
              validValContent = ws.getCell(i, 5).getValue().toString().trim();
              newVariable = ws.getCell(i, 0).getValue().toString().trim();

            } while (validValContent != "" && newVariable == "");

            --i;

          }

          RDS.Variables.push(variable);

        }
      };

      libContent.Modules.push(RDS);

    }
  });

  return libContent;
}

interface clsLibraryContent {
  Filename: string;
  Modules: clsModule[];
}
interface clsModule {
  TabName: string;
  Header: string;
  Description: string;
  Label: string;
  Name: string;
  KeyStructure: string;
  CurrentVersion: string;
  PreviousVersion: string;
  Comments: string;
  Variables: clsVariable[];
}
interface clsVariable {
  Name: string;
  Label: string;
  Type: string;
  CollectionLength: string;
  Format: string;
  Class: string;
  Required: string;
  [Config: string]: string;
  ValidValues: clsValidValue[];
}
interface clsValidValue {
  CodedValue: string;
  UserString: string;
}
```

I tried to remove all lines of code and reenter line by line, but I didn't figure out which line made the script invalid. I also tried to readd the Excel connector in PA, it failed.

Comment: When I copy the script you shared into the code editor, I'm getting errors on lines 42 and 128 related to your definition of `clsVariable`. It looks as though you've defined an index signature that requires all properties of `clsVariable` to be a string, but `ValidValues` is an array, which is incompatible. Are you also seeing this error in your own code editor?

Comment: Yes, I see also that when I this line is not a comment. If I make it a comment, this doesn/t help. And it is weird for me as in the top object (line 6 and first interface), you also have an array: Modules: clsModule[]. Is that also incorrect?

Comment: You are close to my answer, as I removed all of arrays in the code and enter the return type as string. But I also changed the retun line to "return draftTab;"
Thenafter the window to add a parameter "draftTab" appears. 
According to this article, object return type is allowed and I managed to do that previously (using all of the nested interfaces on the bottom of code):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/power-automate-parameters-returns

Answer (score 1):

The answer for why your script fails as is is that the interface

```
interface clsVariable {
  Name: string;
  Label: string;
  Type: string;
  CollectionLength: string;
  Format: string;
  Class: string;
  Required: string;
  [Config: string]: string;
  ValidValues: clsValidValue[];
}
```

contains `[Config: string]: string;`. This property means that you can have arbitrary values in your return value. This breaks PA because PA will not be able to parse your script and determine what your return value is at design time (aka while you're creating the PA Flow). PA needs to know what types your script uses for both parameters and return values so that the dynamic variables can be gleaned and used in subsequent actions.

And just as an fyi,

```
interface clsVariable {
  ...
  [Config: string]: string | clsValidValue[];
  ValidValues: clsValidValue[];
}
```

would be the correct syntax for this type of interface that contains a property declaring arbitrary values. This will get rid of your red squigglies. This happens because `[Config: string]: string;` states that all of the properties in this interface are of type `string`, which obviously collides with the `ValidValues: clsValidValue[];` property.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite surprised that I didn't find the answer before posting this question.
The really easy answer is that you can use JSON objects and methods:
JSON.stringify() to return a string parameter to PowerAutomate
JSON.parse() to rebuild the structure in the second script.
This is supereasy and flexible.
PS. Sorry Admin for spam :)